# wp-config.php external access

Tags: wordpress, api, get, cpanel

i need a function to get wp-config database, user, and pass from another server.

I find this, but only work in the same cpanel account. Is there any way to fetch this values?

```
    $f = "/home/".$ac["user"]."/www/wp/wp-config.php";
        if(file_exists($f)) {
            $c = file_get_contents($f);

            preg_match('/define.*DB_NAME.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
            $dbname = $m[1];

            preg_match('/define.*DB_USER.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
            $dbuser = $m[1];

            preg_match('/define.*DB_PASSWORD.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
            $dbpass = $m[1];

            preg_match('/define.*DB_HOST.*\'(.*)\'/', $c, $m);
            $dbhost = $m[1];
```

Comment: there should be NO way from parsing the information from a wp-config.php file from outside of your own server structure, this would be a massive security issue. If it was the case, i could get the login details for any wordpress site!

Answer (score 0):

wp-config is written in PHP. PHP is a server side language, meaning you can't get the information out of the script itself, only what it outputs. Not only that, but it would be a major security flaw if you were able to do that to just anyone's Wordpress installation. If your needing that information, the only way would be to get access to the file itself such as via FTP.

Comment: `PHP is a server side language, meaning you can't get the information out of the script itself, only what it outputs.`. You are wrong. I CAN get info from the PHP file as well as any file in the file system. For example, I create a PHP file `test.php` with the following line `<?php $i = 'hello';?>`. After that I create the another PHP file to get a content of `test.php` using `<?php header('Content-type: text/plain'); var_dump(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/test.php'));`. And I receive: `string(21) "<?php $i = 'hello';?>"`.

Comment: @Mikhail, you are correct, you can do that... within your own server infrastructure. That's not what PHP is designed or used for, nor is it what the OP was asking for. The OP wants to get the source from a REMOTE file. Run your example code on a file outside your server and the output will only be whatever the script outputs, and not the source. Unless the server is improperly configured, what the OP is asking for cannot be done as it would be a security nightmare.

Comment: no it is in the same server, a vps.
there is any way to read directly on linux trough php?

Comment: @Andre, your original question states "from another server". A VPS is a virtual private server, meaning its private/separate from all the other servers even though its on the same hardware. So you need to more clearly state what it is exactly your trying to do. Unless the config file is in the same file system as the php script, what you are asking for cant be done. If the config is in the same file system then at that point its a million times easier to just FTP in and download the config file. It doesn't sound like you have access in that way, hence why its not possible.